# Defining names in place of "true" and "false" for bool type

Tags: c++, boolean, c-preprocessor

I am wanting to use a `bool` to switch back and forth between loading X and loading Y from a file. I don't want to use "true" and "false", because it doesn't make the code clear. I would rather use something like LOAD_X or LOAD_Y... Is the following code the way to do it? Or is there a better way?

```
#define LOAD_X true
#define LOAD_Y false
```

Edit: Okay, so it seems an `enum` is the way to go... but what should the naming scheme be? Like all caps, or lower case for the first word, uppercase for following words, etc.

Comment: Just wait until someone comes along and writes `if(LOAD_Y)`...

Comment: @Anon Why would anyone do that?

Comment: @Tomalak: Probably the same reason anyone would ever leak memory or double-free something. Making it easy to screw up (and making it *actually look pretty correct* when it's screwed up) is a terrible thing.

Comment: This kind of situation is exactly what enums were intended for.

Comment: @Anon: doesn't matter much if `LOAD_X`/`LOAD_Y` are aliases for `true`/`false`, number, or enums - in any of these cases they could be abused just as easily in an `if` condition.

Comment: @Michael: The difference is that `if(SomeEnum)` is quite obviously wrong. Whereas the difference between `if(COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANT)` and `if(MACRO_MASQUERADING_AS_AN_ENUM)` is non-existent when just looking at the code in question.

Comment: @Jay:  Concerning naming, name the enumeration and its enumerators whatever you'd like.  Use capital letters, don't use capital letters, whatever.  However you choose to name them, just be consistent in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use an enum instead.  Just because there are two choices, doesn't mean the type should be bool

```
enum load_type { loadX, loadY };
```

Comment: If you like caps, go for it.  The standard library doesn't use them for enums.

Comment: @litb: Caps for all constants and macros! Non-caps for things you can assign to and stuff!

Comment: @LouFranco: I'd hardly hold up the Standard Library as an example of good design.

Comment: @Tomalak "all" the "well-designed" libs like qt and llvm use non-caps for constants.

Comment: @litb: I'm shocked and appalled. Tell me at least that Boost uses caps, please.

Comment: @LouFranco: This interesting thread covers the topic quite well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/777641/why-are-all-caps-constant-considered-bad-coding-style

Comment: @Tomalak, yes -- I agree that macros should use ALLCAPS.  Since I didn't use a macro, I didn't use them.

Comment: @LouFranco: I merely posted a link to a conversation on the issue. I already know where you stand. :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use an enum:

```
enum LoadType {
    LoadY,
    LoadX
};
```

Or, you might prefer to constrain the scope of the enumerators by using a namespace:

```
namespace LoadType {
    enum Type {
        LoadY,
        LoadX
    };
};
```

The advantage of using an enum is that if your function takes a `LoadType` (or a `LoadType::Type` in the second example), you can't pass it any arbitrary integer or bool; you can only pass it one of the enumerators (or something explicitly cast to the enumeration type, which is really easy to spot in a code review).

Comment: "you can't pass it any arbitrary integer or bool; you can only pass it one of the enumerators" Not in C++. In C++, an integer will be implicitly converted to a plain enum. However, as of C++11, scoped enumerations are now available which _are_ typesafe.

Answer (score 3):

I guess that works, if you'll only ever have two options. I'd be tempted to go for an enum:

```
enum LOADMODE {
    LOAD_X,
    LOAD_Y
};
```

At the very least, prefer constants over macros:

```
const bool LOAD_X = true;
const bool LOAD_Y = false;
```

They will abide by scope rules and won't silently break stuff without you realising when names conflict.

Comment: I enjoy enums too much, but at least in C++98 I think I would go with the constants, if only because enum value names are available in whatever namespace the enum is in. Fortunately C++0x introduces the `enum class` which, among other things, doesn't do so, making something like `enum class load { X, Y };` possible with `X` and `Y` unable to conflict with anything.

Comment: @fow:  You can easily wrap an enumeration in a namespace or class to constrain the scope of the enumerators.

Comment: @fow The constants are available in whatever namespace they're defined in, too.

Comment: what if you define either of these in a class? it would stay in the class only, right?

Comment: Right. I just wanted to mention `enum class` because, like I said, I enjoy enums too much. :)

Comment: @fow: There are medical professionals that can help you with that. :P

Answer (score -1):

i think Load X IS LOAD.
Lowercase font look more friendly, you can choose bright colors.
enum LoadType {
    LoadY,
    LoadX
it is all right.