# A few C# naming convention questions

Tags: c#, variables, naming-conventions, constants, private

1)
What's the policy for declaring a variable? Should you **always** use the keyword `private`, or is it OK to skip it?

```
string MyVar1;
```

vs.

```
private string MyVar1;
```

The only reason I see is that Microsoft one day can change the default access modifiers to `public` instead of `private`.

**Where** does it say that private is optional? Any references to [MSDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Developer_Network)?

2)
Naming policy for constants?

I have always used caps when writing a constant, but a friend told me that it's against the Microsoft naming policy, is it?

```
const string MYVAR1;
```

vs

```
const string myVar1;
```

3)
Pascal or Camel?

Personally I think that Camel just looks ugly.

Comment: Just a suggestion, but you might want to retitle this question with something more informative than 'A few C# Questions' so future SO users can find what they need. Ideally, these would have been three different SO questions, though I'm sure some of these have been asked before.

Comment: Good point, i changed the title to better indicate the nature of the questions

Comment: By the way, THESE_CONSTANT_VARIABLES are the convention in C++. (And as the answers mentioned, not in C#)

Answer (score 22):

1) The `private` keyword is optional.  I highly doubt that Microsoft will ever change the default visibility of fields as this would be a massive, breaking change (not to mention a stupid one).  Omitting the `private` keyword is merely a matter of personal taste.

2) Don't use "shouty" constants - follow the convention of the framework and use pascal casing (e.g. `ThisIsAConstant` is preferable over THIS_IS_A_CONSTANT).

Comment: I'd add that whilst private is optional, at least be consistent in your code base. That is, use it or don't use it - don't mix.

Comment: I_AM_AN_OBNOXIOUS_CONSTANT_OOOOH_LOOK_AT_ME_THEN

Comment: I still can't find where it states that constants should not be all capped.

Comment: "They shouldn't because it's annoying and hard to read. – Rex M 1 min ago"

Why would it be harder to read them, they just note "Hey! I'm a constant"

Comment: @Patrick: Read through http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(VS.71).aspx. I also wrote a little program once that spat out all constant names in the common BCL assemblies. Pascal casing is the way to go.

Comment: @Rex M. - The illegibility of an identifier is subjective.  You cannot say that because _you_ find them hard to read that they are in fact that way.  By commenting that "all-caps words are hard to read" you are in fact making a statement about yourself, not the naming convention.  The fact remains that you find them hard to read; someone else could just as easily find them easier to read.  It is a common mistake to consider a consensus of opinion as a well-known fact.  Subjective opinions are still subjective opinions regardless of how many people share them.

Comment: @Rex M. - I do agree that screaming caps _are_ harder to read :)  Still, the better argument to make is that the .NET framework and all corresponding design documentation lays out that pascal casing should be used for identifier names, including constants.  This is an objective argument that is sound and follows from a valid premise.

Comment: Here's *why* screaming caps are harder to read: It's because they don't have the ascenders and descenders that lowercase letters have.  Lowercase letters can be distinguished by height, not just by shape, whereas capital letters can be distinguished only by shape.

Comment: All caps is not harder to read, it's just different, making them easier to identify quickly. That's the whole reason it was done in the first place though... The MS guidelines make consts look like regular classes to me.

Answer (score 13):

You might be interested in Microsoft's [Design Guidelines For Class Library Developers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czefa0ke%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

Not answering your question directly, but maybe you would be interested in Microsoft's [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis).  This is a tool for analysing your source code with respect to style and consistency rules.  By default, it imposes Microsoft's styling guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

The official recommendation for naming consts according to the MS guidelines, since no-one has actually specified it fully yet is:

- **Use all caps for names with one or two characters** i.e. System.Math.PI, System.Math.E
- For **anything equal to or over 3 characters, use PascalCasing**.

Answer (score 1):

private is optional, but extra typing. I like to skip it.

As for the constancts, It depends on your preferences and who you're working with. But when in doubt, look at the .NET Framework and how they name constants.

Comment: But where is that stated on the Microsoft webpage? Where does it say that private is optional?

Everyone know's it, but where is it written?

Comment: @Patrick: you might take a look at the C# language specification:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336809.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Also private field names should be in camel case, optionaly with prefix _ or m_ :

```
    private int count;
or
    private string _name;
or
    private decimal m_price;
```

Comment: I can't find that anywhere on the Microsoft webpage.

Comment: It's a common practice - all private fields in MSDN examples is camel case.

Comment: I can't find that either on MSDN, it states only that normal variables should be written using pascal case. It doesn't say anything about prefixes.
Any references?

Comment: _ and m_ break Intellisense.  They may help in C++, but in C# you're shooting yourself in the foot with them.

Comment: Simon that's not true. Especially if you use great tool Resharper 4.x - it actually by default forces _cameCase convention (which can be adjusted of course).

Comment: Speaking from experience, "m_" doesn't break Intellisense.  If it breaks yours then something is wrong with your setup.  "m_" is actually really nice because as soon as you start typing it, you get all of of other private vars which follow the same naming convention in Intellisense

Comment: However, if you are using a private constant field you should name it using PascalCase. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/242545/1698964 for details.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt Microsoft is ever going to change the default behavior for C# member variables. I would declare things private you want to be private and explicitly declare things public that you want to be public just for clarity if nothing else.

I think the important rule for constants is to just use a naming convention everyone agrees on and that you recognize as a constant. If everyone likes all upper case then use that. If you want to be more standard though use Pascal casing.

Comment: Why Pascal and not Camel casing?

Answer (score 1):

**private** is optional, so you can skip it.

However, if your class has a mix of private, protected and public data members, it may be a good idea to specify that a member is private for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would love it if constants were ALL_CAPS like in some other languages...I think that it's an quick and easy way to spot constants.  Nevertheless, since other constants built into the framework UsePascalCasing, you should too.  Consistency is very important.

As far as "Pascal vs. Camel", you run into the same issue.  If you were just programming on your own, from scratch, you could do whatever you wanted.  But since you're using a preexisting framework, for the sake of consistency, you should emulate the same style.  Additionally, once you get used to it, you'll probably find that following the same set of rules will actually help, because you'll instantly know that something is a parameter or local variable (camelCasing) vs a property or constant (PascalCasing).

Answer (score 1):

> Do use Pascal casing in field names.

From [.NET Framework Developer's Guide
Names of Type Members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)

> Do use Pascal casing for all public
>   member, type, and namespace names
>   consisting of multiple words.
>
> Note that this rule does not apply to
>   instance fields. For reasons that are
>   detailed in the Member Design
>   Guidelines, you should not use public
>   instance fields.

From [.NET Framework Developer's Guide
Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx)

Note the implied standard of Pascal casing in constant naming.

> DO use constant fields for constants
>   that will never change.
>
> The compiler burns the values of const
>   fields directly into calling code.
>   Therefore, const values can never be
>   changed without the risk of breaking
>   compatibility.
>
> ```
> public struct Int32 {
>   public const int MaxValue = 0x7fffffff;
>   public const int MinValue = unchecked((int)0x80000000);
> }
> ```

From Framework Design Guidelines: Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .NET Libraries, Second Edition page 161

I cannot find any reference to whether you should decorate private fields with the term private.  that is more of an internal style choice i would assume.  Which ever you pick you will want to stay consistent.

Answer (score 0):

1) I tend to use private, just to be explicit, but there really is no need to I guess

2) It's true, Microsoft do recommend not using caps for constants.

Microsoft's naming convention gyuidelines for type members can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a free ebook with C# and VB .net coding guidelines, it's very good

[Link to ebook download](http://submain.com/products/guidelines.aspx)

Personally though, I like explicitly specifying when something is private, for readability, in fact I'm so used to doing so that when I don't see it I get confused. As for constants, I use PascalCasing.

Answer (score 0):

You may also be interested in **Microsoft's own Internal Coding Guidelines** for the .NET Framework, as [revealed by Brad Abrams in his blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/articles/361363.aspx):

Follow all .NET Framework Design Guidelines for both internal and external members. Highlights of these include:

- Do not use Hungarian notation
- Do not use a prefix for member variables (*, m*, s_, etc.). If you want to distinguish
- between local and member variables you should use “this.” in C# and “Me.” in VB.NET.
- Do use camelCasing for member variables
- Do use camelCasing for parameters
- Do use camelCasing for local variables
- Do use PascalCasing for function, property, event, and class names
- Do prefix interfaces names with “I”
- Do not prefix enums, classes, or delegates with any letter

Answer (score 0):

@Dan Diplo
    # Do not use a prefix for member variables (, m, s_, etc.). If you want to distinguish # between local and member variables you should use “this.” in C# and “Me.” in VB.NET.

That's highly arguable. Prefix helps intellisense: you put prefix char and get a list only of local private instance fields. With this. you will get a full list which consists of methods, fields, properties, events ect.

Consider also following example:

```
private int _count; 
private int total; 
private decimal price; 

public MyClass(int count, int total, decimal price) 
{ 
    _count = count;     // correct 
    this.total = total; // correct 
    price = price;      // wrong! you forgot this. qualifier 
}
```

Comment: Actually, I personally do use underscore for private member variables (habit). I was just pointing out what Microsoft's own internal coding guidelines state.

Comment: Microsoft actually uses m_ prefix for private members of .NET FW classes.

Answer (score 0):

In C# visibility defaults to the most limited visibility possible.  Without a modifier:

- non-inner classes are internal
- inner classes are private
- class members are private

Because it's a good idea to limit visibility as much as possible anyway, I try to *always* leave off the modifier where the default visibility is all I need.  This makes those members that *aren't* the default more obvious, which helps keep me attentive to whether they really need to be that visible.

For constants, my preference would be to put them in their own class(es) so that the ClassName.ConstantName format makes it obvious what they are.

In general I follow Microsoft's [Design Guidelines for Developing Class Libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx).