# What should be the standard for private class constants in C#?

Tags: c#, coding-style

For those of you that use the underscore prefix for private class members in C# (i.e. private int _count;), what do you use for private constants?  I'm thinking the following but am curious as to what others are doing.

```
private const int _MaxCount;
```

Comment: Asked before at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242534/c-naming-convention-for-constants

But I see from Martin's answer he's already been there. ;)

Comment: In fact I haven't been there - otherwise I would have used TheAnswer as the name of the constant ;-)

Comment: Good point, so my apologies. If my brain didn't hurt so much I should have expected that 42 is always the answer when you need a random number. But what was the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, private is private, so chose the convention you like best. I personally use PascalCasing, e.g:

```
private const int SomeConstant = 42;
```

---

This is what [MSDN has to say about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229012.aspx):

The naming guidelines for fields apply to static public and protected fields. You should not define public or protected instance fields:

- Do use Pascal casing in field names.
- Do name fields with nouns or noun phrases.
- Do not use a prefix for field names. For example, do not use g_ or s_ to distinguish static versus non-static fields.

Comment: It says: use `camelCase` for private fields (constants are technically fields too): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2dbyw72(VS.71).aspx

Comment: The problem I have with this is that Pascal casing is also used for Properties.  I'd like to look at a variable and know it is a variable, not a property.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using:

```
private const int MAX_COUNT = 42;
```

I do not use *PascalCasing* because that's my standard for properties.
I do not use *camelCasing* because that's my standard for local variables.
I do not use _camelCasing because that's my standard for private fields.
I do not use _PascalCasing because IMO it's hard to distinguish it from _camelCasing.

Answer (score 2):

C# and .NET naming conventions discourage all prefixes (e.g. `C`, `i`, `s_`, `g_`, `m_`, `_`) except "`I`" for interface names and "`T`" for type parameters.

Comment: And a T prefix for generic types?

Comment: Do you have a reference to that? As far as I remember these conventions only cover the public parts, but not private.

Comment: Charlie: Yeah. I missed that one. Thanks for pointing it out. Actually, not the types themselves. T for type parameters.

Comment: Martin: There's a naming convention document out there. The thing you are mentioning is the common language specification naming standards. They are actually **enforced** if you want your assembly to be `[CLSCompliant(true)]` and they only cover public names but the conventions apply to all cases (and they are just conventions.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand why prefixes are discouraged?  If I don't use them, I can't immediately identify that a variable is a class variable or a local variable.

Comment: Brandon: I can think of some reasons but I'm just quoting the .NET framework naming guidelines published by MS. This is their decision.

Answer (score 0):

The naming guidelines are available here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx

As Mehrdad said, [prefixes are specifically discouraged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045.aspx).

That said, they are just guidelines more than hard rules.  Personally, I use an '_' prefix, but only for private members *that directly provide the backing store for a public property,* and then the names will otherwise match exactly.

There's no specific guidance for constants, so the [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx) rules probably still fit.