# Naming local constants: UpperCamelCase or lowerCamelCase?

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, constants, camelcasing

Which naming convention do you use for **local constants** in **C#** and why?

```
const int Pi = 3;
const int pi = 3;
```

It seems the trade-off is between lower camel-case indicating restricted scope, and upper camel-case being more readable and easier to move to a class level. I've noticed **StyleCop** prefers upper camel-case.

Comment: **Related:** [C# naming convention for constants?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/242534/1497596)

Comment: Microsoft refers to these naming conventions as **PascalCasing** and **camelCasing**. See the MSDN article [Capitalization Conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx). Also, please keep in mind that [pi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) is arguably not a good example to use in this question since it is already defined in the .NET class library as [Math.PI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435490.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm used to upper case (pascal case) for everything except variables and fields. Global constants are an exception to the fields, I don't know why, probably because they are public in some cases. Local constants are also lowercase so.

It's just a matter of taste imo. Of course, within a product / team, there should be an agreement.

On the other hand, our coding guideline requires full uppercase for constants, this would be `PI` in this case. I don't like this because upper cases are hard to read and need underlines for separation (which is against code analysis rules). Nobody follows this guideline anymore.

Answer (score 6):

We use lower-case (camel casing) because local constants are almost local variables except of course you cannot modify them. (And we use camel casing for local variables of course...)

Comment: local variable naming convention regardless of constant or not. period! up vote!