# How to use switch case block in c# properly?

Tags: c#, switch-statement

I have a switch case statements in c#, here all the cases i made as private constants ,is there any bad programming practice going on here, or do i need to use enumeration here and enumerator in case block.Only three constants i showed here, i have ten constants and ten case block

```
private const String FEASIBLESIZE = "Total FEASIBLESIZE";
private const String AVAILABLESIZE = "Total AVAILABLESIZE";
private const String EXCESSSIZE = "Total EXCESSSIZE";
                          .
                          . 
switch (value.ToString())
{
    case FEASIBLESIZE:
        Level.Add(TEAMSIZE, test.ToString());
        break;

    case AVAILABLESIZE:
        Level.Add(BROADSIZE, test.ToString());                                
        break;

    case EXCESSSIZE:
        Level.Add(NARROWSIZE, test.ToString());
        break;
         .
         .
         .
```

Comment: ALLCAPS makes your C# code look like something written in COBOL in the  early 70s.

Comment: Something smells here. Why do you convert Value to string?

Comment: Uppercase is often used for constants in c#, which is this case.

Comment: @TomasGrosup, yes, as we can see in this question this is unfortunately is still the case. But this doesn't mean that the [standard C# naming conventions](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices) recommend it. Let me quote: `Do not use SCREAMING_CAPS`. So yeah, the fact that some people are still using this completely horrible convention doesn't mean that this is the C# standard convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your constants appear to be a candidate for Enum, I would go for Enum rather than const here....

Comment: good does it has any perfomance impacts? i think so can you explain the reason?

Comment: Based on your const values looks like they all describe Size so they are kind of a group so better to group them in an Enum. And I suppose Enum comparison in switch case should be faster.

Comment: @vettori  doesn't Oded's solution impress you? If my logic allowed I would go for what he suggested...You could still go for Enum the Dictionary<string,string> becomes Dictionary<yourEnum,string>

Answer (score 5):

Aside from the horrible formatting it looks roughly okay. Of course that's a bit hard to tell without actually knowing your code. Darin is correct though, in that you're not adhering to the default naming conventions (all caps is a no-go anywhere in C#).

But I have seen much worse, if that's any consolation.

Comment: +1 for `I have seen much worse, if that's any consolation` :-)

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing looks like something that can be replaced using a `Dictionary<string,string>` mapping from one size type to another.

```
var sizeMap = new Dictionary<string,string>();

sizeMap.Add(FEASIBLESIZE, TEAMSIZE);
sizeMap.Add(AVAILABLESIZE, BROADSIZE);
sizeMap.Add(EXCESSSIZE, NARROWSIZE);
```

And instead of the switch:

```
Level.Add(sizeMap[value.ToString()], test.ToString());
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try to scope the case with curly braces this is just individual style but helps  when lines of code grows up and also always use the default: too

```
case FEASIBLESIZE:
{
  Level.Add(TEAMSIZE, test.ToString());
  break;
}
default:
///...
break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Bad Programming Practice:

```
private const String FEASIBLESIZE = "Total FEASIBLESIZE";
```

Good Programming Practice:

```
private const String FEASIBLE_SIZE = "Total FEASIBLESIZE";
```

Better Programming Practice:

```
private const String FeasibleSize = "Total FEASIBLESIZE";
```

Comment: FEASIBLE_SIZE is a definite improvement over FEASIBLESIZE but AFAIK the recommended style for c# is FeasibleSize.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/242534/c-sharp-naming-convention-for-constants.

Comment: @AlanT: AFAIK `FeasibleSize` is to use with variables, and `FEASIBLE_SIZE` with constant.