# C# - basic if statement inquiry - can't find the answer

Tags: c#, if-statement

this has probably been answered but i don't know how to frame the question, therefore can't find a past answer.

so what i wanna do is something like this: (more variables for the same if check)

```
if ((aa && bb && cc) == 1)
    {
       win = 1;
    }
```

what's the correct syntax for this?

thanks a bunch

Comment: What are `aa`, `bb` and `cc` exactly? What do you wanna check? Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @SonerGönül I think he means to check if all three variables equal 1.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: you mean `if (aa == 1 && bb == 1 && cc == 1)`? You could explain by words what you really want.

Answer (score 2):

if you have many variables, you could also build an array of the values and use the IEnumerable.All method to verify they're all 1. More readable, IMO.

```
if (new[] { aa, bb, cc}.All(x => x == 1))
```

Comment: Very complicated for such a simple task, or?

Comment: nope, he has mention he wants to check more variable. so this approach would be easier

Answer (score 1):

```
if (aa == 1 && bb == 1 && cc == 1)
{
   win = 1;
}
```

Comment: @cFrozenDeath [Answers can be only code if the code is self explanatory](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258673/can-code-only-answers-be-high-quality). Seeing as how guy just rewrote the asker's code to use the correct syntax, I don't see how this would be a bad answer.

Comment: @MageXy he should have mentioned why the checking needs to be done per variable, and why it cannot be done with code posted by the OP

Comment: @cFrozenDeath The OP already knows his code is syntactically incorrect - that's his question.  He specifically asks for the correct syntax. This answer gives that info.

Answer (score 1):

You could check each variable individually, such as the following:

```
if (aa == 1 && bb == 1 && cc == 1)
{
    // do something
}
```

If you know that you'll always be checking against the value of 1, you may want to declare it as a constant.

```
public const int ExpectedValue= 1;
if (aa == ExpectedValue&& bb == ExpectedValue&& cc == ExpectedValue)
{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: FWIW, .NET naming conventions would make that `ExpectedValue`.

Comment: So it would be.  I learned something new... http://stackoverflow.com/a/242549/3033053

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you will have to do it the long way,
There is no simple short clean way of checking if multiple vars have the same value in an if statement.

Code:

```
If (aa == 1 && bb == 1 && cc == 1)
{
    // Code here.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The data type of the variable does make a difference as to what you could do with the `if` statement.

---

### Boolean

If they are `boolean` values and you want to know when they are one, you can go:

```
if(aa && bb && cc) { }
```

Because each variable is either one or zero, if one of them were false then the whole statement would be false. Only, when all are one will this statement be true.

---

### Integer

If you want to have the look of

```
if((aa && bb && cc) == Value) {}
```

You can multiply them and see if they are equal to the cube of `Value`.

```
if(aa*bb*cc == Value*Value*Value) {}
```

So, if `Value` equals one then you get:

```
if(aa*bb*cc == 1) {}
```

---

### Best Way

The best way to do this would be to individually check that each variable is equal to `Value`.

```
if(aa == Value && bb == Value && cc == Value) {}
```

This is because the `&&` operator expects two `bool`s then returns a `boolean` value. So, when you go `aa && bb && cc` you are literally "anding" these values together to produce a `boolean` value. By first comparing each variable to the `Value` you are creating a `boolean` value for each one then "anding" that together to produce a similar result as the first solution I presented.

---

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code , and its very simple and easy

```
if ( aa == 1 && bb == 2 && cc == 3)
{
    // your codes
}
```